# 筛选 is the correct filter for 'search filter'?

Tags: translation, usage, word-requests

When searching for airline flights, for example, there may be an option to filter by ticket price, or filter by airline, or filter by flight duration.

I am looking for the Chinese translation of "filter" in this sense.

I am not sure if 筛选 is correct.

Comment: yes, you are correct. go ahead

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E7%AD%9B%E9%80%89

It's a more sophisticated word than 过滤, which we usually use for filter.

过滤 mean filtering out unwanted substances, like filtering coffee. 
筛选 is more for computer filtering.

Comment: So yeah, since they call it Excel 筛选 (Excel filtering), if you are doing something for programming, 筛选 is the correct word to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely correct

> 【词目】 筛选 
> 【拼音】shāi xuǎn 
> 【释义】利用筛子进行选拣，现泛指通过淘汰的方式挑选。
>  【示例】 筛选种子|筛选矿沙。

So, yes, we use `筛选` on the Internet, `过滤` is more technical

> 过滤一下烧杯